# QuickForm2 - client side validation

Tags: php, javascript, pear, quickform

http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2/
http://download.pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2-0.6.1.tgz

I am able to use this fine for forms but I'm having problems getting the client side validation to work.  I don't think I have the correct files and includes but the explanation online is confusing the heck out of me.  There's an example file that I'm trying to load (builtin-rules.php) but the javascript doesn't work.  Here is an excerpt that I think should validate using ONBLUR event but it doesn't.

```
$username->addRule('required', 'Username is required', null,
               HTML_QuickForm2_Rule::ONBLUR_CLIENT_SERVER);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just updated [the docs which deal with including JS files](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform2.javascript.php#package.html.html-quickform2.javascript.libraries). Hopefully they should be clearer now.

Comment: BTW, if you have trouble running even the package examples, then you probably copied some files around manually and the package cannot find them. See [a similar bug report](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=19311)

Comment: Got it working now with your help and getting a little basic javascript reading done.  I included them myself and had to obtain the .js file by manually downloading the package.  Thank you, I will vote as answer as soon as I get some more rep points.

Answer (score 0):

This if from their [documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform2.javascript.php):

```
<?php
require_once 'HTML/QuickForm2/Renderer.php';
require_once 'HTML/QuickForm2/JavascriptBuilder.php';

$renderer = HTML_QuickForm2_Renderer::factory('default');
// Here '/path/to/libraries' is whatever directory available via HTTP you copied libraries to
$renderer->setJavascriptBuilder(new HTML_QuickForm2_JavascriptBuilder('/path/to/libraries'));
$form->render($renderer);

// This will output necessary <script src="/path/to/libraries/..."></script> tags
foreach ($renderer->getJavascriptBuilder()->getLibraries() as $link) {
    echo $link . "\n";
}
echo $renderer;
?>
```